# Unity3D Openfeint Xcode 4.1 C++ headers compiled as C

Tags: xcode4, header, compilation, unity-game-engine, openfeint

I am trying to integrate the openfeint unity plugin into our game, 
I got the xCode project, followed the steps from [Openfeint Support Page](http://support.openfeint.com/dev/example-integrating-ofunity-for-ios-with-unity/) but when trying to compile the proiect openfeint's header files are compiled as C files not as C++.

I tried almost everything without cuccess. I added the -ObjC build flag,
and GCC_OBJC_CALL_CXX_CDTORS = YES in the setting of GCC .

Any ideas what went wrong?
P.S. I also get the error message from Openfeint.h:

```
 #ifndef __cplusplus
#error "OpenFeint requires Objective-C++. In XCode, you can enable this by changing your file's extension to .mm" #endif
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't treat header files as compilation targets at all.

Either you are somehow marking header files for compilation, or including them in .m files, which are Objective-C (as opposed to .mm files, which are Objective-C++). Assuming the latter — which is the more likely scenario — you can simply rename the affected .m files to .mm.

Comment: I checked, they are included into the Appcontroller+Openfeint.mm, I run the same project unde Xcode 3.4 and everything was ok, but under 4.1 I can't fix this

Comment: Under the file inspector, is the File Type for that file listed as "Default - Objective-C++ Source"?

Comment: Yes, it's  "Default - Objective-C++ Source"